# cursorindexoutofboundsexception

Tags: android

I'm currently doing my final year project on android app. I tried to make a login module, but it always gives me an error for that part:

> android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1

"size of 1" is the user data that I try to get; however, I can't figure out where to go from here. Can anyone help me solve this issue? Here's my code:

```
    Cursor c = agentDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(username) FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE + " WHERE " + KEY_USERNAME + " = ? AND " +KEY_PASSWORD + " = ?", new String[]{user, pass});

    String result = "";

    if(c != null && c.moveToPosition(0)){
        //if (c.moveToFirst()){

            int r = c.getCount();

            if(r == 1){
                //Cursor d = agentDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE + " WHERE " + KEY_USERNAME + " = '" + user + "'", new String[]{ KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_EMAIL, KEY_USERNAME});

                Cursor d = agentDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE + " WHERE " + KEY_USERNAME + " = ?", new String[]{user});

                int iRow = d.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
                int iName = d.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);
                int iEmail = d.getColumnIndex(KEY_EMAIL);
                int iUser = d.getColumnIndex(KEY_USERNAME);

                result = result + d.getString(iRow) + " " + d.getString(iUser) + " " + d.getString(iName) + " " + d.getString(iEmail) + "\n";

            }
        //}
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: I know nothing about Android databases, but don't you also need a `.moveToPosition` on `d`?

Comment: Indeed, and c.moveToFirst() is a bit nicer

Comment: Try `d.moveToFirst()` before fetch values from it.

Comment: Why you are making it so complex 

you can use this as: c.moveToFirst & d.moveToFirst

Comment: i don't know how to simplify it.....i've change c and d...now i got new error tho

Answer (score 1):

You should move the Cursor to the first row before fetching data

```
Cursor d = agentDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE + " WHERE " + KEY_USERNAME + " = ?", new String[]{user});
d.moveToFirst();
```

This will work if you only expect one row in the result cursor, otherwise you can use `d.move`.

Comment: i've change it.....both c and d.....now i get this error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0,col -1 from CursorWindow.
Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it

Comment: Take a look at this question and see if it helps: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9029668/android-sqlite-cursor-getcolumnindex-is-case-sensitive)

Comment: okay.....finally my login is complete.....thank guys.....hope you all can help me in the future......;)