# FC when looking for record in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

I have several methods for getting a record in my app
But for some reason this one keeps giving me FC !
I'm using the following method to get the Cursor :

```
Cursor c=helper.getRecordById(num);
```

Which is implemented as follows :

```
public Cursor getRecordById(int rowId) {
    String rowIDs=""+rowId;
    String SelectById = "SELECT id, OrderName, OrderLink, DateYear, DateMonth, DateDay, OrderPrice FROM Orders WHERE id=?";
    String[] args={rowIDs};
    return(getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(SelectById, args));
}
```

I have tried also without converting the Int to String but i just left it this way.. get the same error for both ways.

Whenever i get to the following line :

```
String name=c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("OrderName"));
```

I get the FC.
The GetColumnIndex works just fine... i've tested it exclusively.
But the getString throws the error. :

```
06-02 21:07:13.656: W/KeyCharacterMap(4329): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
06-02 21:07:16.006: D/AndroidRuntime(4329): Shutting down VM
06-02 21:07:16.006: W/dalvikvm(4329): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
06-02 21:07:16.026: E/AndroidRuntime(4329): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-02 21:07:16.026: E/AndroidRuntime(4329): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.Sagi.MyOrders/com.Sagi.MyOrders.DisplayRecord}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 0
06-02 21:07:16.026: E/AndroidRuntime(4329):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
06-02 21:07:16.026: E/AndroidRuntime(4329):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
06-02 21:07:16.026: E/AndroidRuntime(4329):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
06-02 21:07:16.026: E/AndroidRuntime(4329):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
06-02 21:07:16.026: E/AndroidRuntime(4329):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-02 21:07:16.026: E/AndroidRuntime(4329):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-02 21:07:16.026: E/AndroidRuntime(4329):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
06-02 21:07:16.026: E/AndroidRuntime(4329):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-02 21:07:16.026: E/AndroidRuntime(4329):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-02 21:07:16.026: E/AndroidRuntime(4329):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
06-02 21:07:16.026: E/AndroidRuntime(4329):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
06-02 21:07:16.026: E/AndroidRuntime(4329):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-02 21:07:16.026: E/AndroidRuntime(4329): Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 0
06-02 21:07:16.026: E/AndroidRuntime(4329):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:580)
06-02 21:07:16.026: E/AndroidRuntime(4329):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:214)
06-02 21:07:16.026: E/AndroidRuntime(4329):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:41)
06-02 21:07:16.026: E/AndroidRuntime(4329):     at com.Sagi.MyOrders.DisplayRecord.onCreate(DisplayRecord.java:48)
06-02 21:07:16.026: E/AndroidRuntime(4329):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
06-02 21:07:16.026: E/AndroidRuntime(4329):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
06-02 21:07:16.026: E/AndroidRuntime(4329):     ... 11 more
06-02 21:12:16.126: I/Process(4329): Sending signal. PID: 4329 SIG: 9
```

**The funny thing is i copied the same exact Lookup method i used in another place which works just fine !, i even tried giving it a constant to look for which i know to exists just to check. but nothing. error over and over again !**

**Thanks !!!**

Comment: getColumnIndex() is case sensitive:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9029668/android-sqlite-cursor-getcolumnindex-is-case-sensitive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Cursor` initially points to a record one before the start, to allow this kind of code:

```
final Cursor cursor = /* get cursor */;
while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
    /* do something with cursor */
}
```

If you are only expecting one record, and you are sure there will be one record, then before accesing your `Cursor` do:

```
cursor.moveToNext();
```

or:

```
cursor.moveToFirst();
```

Comment: I'm now getting :
06-02 21:40:15.457: E/AndroidRuntime(4678): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.Sagi.MyOrders/com.Sagi.MyOrders.DisplayRecord}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0

Comment: @SagiLow: The error is quite clear, you are trying to access the first element of an empty set. Your cursor has no results and you haven't checked whether `moveTo...()` returned `true`.

Comment: @SagiLow: How rude of you to _un-accept_ my answer just because you made yet another error in your code...

Comment: I figured it out, it wasn't a NULL return but the var i tried to put the String in was uninitialized.