# Inserting into and withdrawing from SQLite database and displaying to a TextView - Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, cursor, illegalstateexception

I am trying to implement a SQLite database for a highscores table.  I am just testing it to see if my database creation, insertion and selecting is working with the below code.  I am trying to insert the first row into the database and then immediately pull from it and display the values to TextViews.  All of the hardcoding is for testing purposes to just get the database working correctly.

I am getting a IllegalStateException on the below lines.  I have commented in the errors on the appropriate lines.

Any additional advice on code structure is much appreciate too.

Thank you in advance!

Highscores.java

```
public class Highscores extends Activity {

    DatabaseHelper dh;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    int percentages;
    long scores;
    TableLayout table;
    TableRow rowHeader, row1, row2, row3, row4, row5, row6, row7, row8, row9, row10;
    TextView rank, percentage, score;
    Button btn1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.highscoresmain);

        dh = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        db = dh.openDB();
        long x = 11;
        int y = 22;
        dh.insert(x, y);
        percentages = dh.getPercentage(db);  //Line 45
        scores = dh.getScore(db);

        Button btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.homeBtn);

        TextView rank = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.rank);
        TextView percentage = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.percentage);
        TextView score = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.score);

        TextView r1r = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.r1r);
        TextView r1p = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.r1p);
        TextView r1s = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.r1s);

        rank.setText("Rank Column - TEST");
        percentage.setText("Percentage Column - TEST ");
        score.setText("Score Column - Test");
        r1r.setText("test..rank");
        r1p.setText(percentages);
        r1s.setText("test..score");

        table = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tableLayout);

              dh.closeDB(db);
         }
       }
```

DatabaseHelper.java

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper { 

    SQLiteDatabase db;

    private static final String TABLE = "HighscoresList"; 
    public static DatabaseHelper mSingleton = null;

    // Table columns names. 
    private static final String RANK = "_id"; 
    private static final String SCORE = "score"; 
    private static final String PERCENTAGE = "percentage";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) { 
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION); 
    }

    public synchronized static DatabaseHelper getInstance(Context context) {
        if(mSingleton == null) {
            mSingleton = new DatabaseHelper(context.getApplicationContext());
        }
        return mSingleton;
    }

    public SQLiteDatabase openDB() {
        db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return db;
    }

          //I am using hard coded numbers in the below 2 methods for testing purposes.
public long getScore(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + SCORE + " FROM " + TABLE + " WHERE " + SCORE + " = " + 11 + ";", null);  //Line 45
    long i = 0;
    if(c.getCount() != 0) {
           c.moveToFirst();
           int columnIndex = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("SCORE"));
           if(columnIndex != -1) {
               i = c.getLong(columnIndex);
           } else { 
               i = 999; 
           }
    } else {
        i = 555;
    }
    c.close();
    return i;
}

public int getPercentage(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + PERCENTAGE + " FROM " + TABLE + " WHERE " + PERCENTAGE + " = " + 22 + ";", null);
    int i = 0;
    if(c.getCount() != 0) {
           c.moveToFirst();
           int columnIndex = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("PERCENTAGE"));
           if(columnIndex != -1) {
               i = c.getInt(columnIndex);
           } else { 
               i = 999; 
           }
    } else {
        i = 555;
    }
    c.close();
    return i;
```

}

```
          //Insert new record.
    public long insert(long score, int percentage) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(SCORE, score);
        values.put(PERCENTAGE, percentage);

        return db.insert(TABLE, null, values);
          }
}
```

LogCat output

```
01-03 15:39:13.952: E/AndroidRuntime(938): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test/com.example.test.Highscores}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
01-03 15:39:13.952: E/AndroidRuntime(938):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
01-03 15:39:13.952: E/AndroidRuntime(938):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
01-03 15:39:13.952: E/AndroidRuntime(938):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-03 15:39:13.952: E/AndroidRuntime(938):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
01-03 15:39:13.952: E/AndroidRuntime(938):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-03 15:39:13.952: E/AndroidRuntime(938):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-03 15:39:13.952: E/AndroidRuntime(938):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
01-03 15:39:13.952: E/AndroidRuntime(938):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-03 15:39:13.952: E/AndroidRuntime(938):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-03 15:39:13.952: E/AndroidRuntime(938):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-03 15:39:13.952: E/AndroidRuntime(938):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-03 15:39:13.952: E/AndroidRuntime(938):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-03 15:39:13.952: E/AndroidRuntime(938): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
01-03 15:39:13.952: E/AndroidRuntime(938):  at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetLong(Native Method)
01-03 15:39:13.952: E/AndroidRuntime(938):  at android.database.CursorWindow.getLong(CursorWindow.java:507)
01-03 15:39:13.952: E/AndroidRuntime(938):  at android.database.CursorWindow.getInt(CursorWindow.java:574)
01-03 15:39:13.952: E/AndroidRuntime(938):  at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getInt(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:69)
01-03 15:39:13.952: E/AndroidRuntime(938):  at com.example.test.DatabaseHelper.getPercentage(DatabaseHelper.java:67)
01-03 15:39:13.952: E/AndroidRuntime(938):  at com.example.test.Highscores.onCreate(Highscores.java:45)
01-03 15:39:13.952: E/AndroidRuntime(938):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
01-03 15:39:13.952: E/AndroidRuntime(938):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
01-03 15:39:13.952: E/AndroidRuntime(938):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
01-03 15:39:13.952: E/AndroidRuntime(938):  ... 11 more
```

**EDIT:**  I updated my `getScore()` and `getPercentage()` methods.  Anyways, I still used some hardcoded numbers so I know exactly what is going on but the program is still crashing.  It seems that the if-else statement should set i to 555 instead of crashing but it isn't.

I updated the LogCat output also.

Comment: your code in `getPercentage()` assumes there is at least one row. apparently there isn't.

Comment: @user1866707 can you update this once you've resolved?  I'm curious as to which answer is correct, but I'm too busy to try it myself, atm

Comment: Sure @MarcoLeblanc.  Emulator is (randomly) being a pain again so I got to get it working first.

Comment: I kind of morphed the two answers into my own but am still getting the same exception, just in a different spot now.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see any database initializing code overriding onCreate but it says your column doesn't exist in the table check it's name again or check the table. Also get into the habit of closing your cursors once your done using them. Otherwise the database will throw errors when you haven't closed a previous cursor.

Just noticed the error its you're using "PERCENTAGE" while you defined it as

```
PERCENTAGE = "percentage";
```

so just be consistent in using the defined variable.

[Android - SQLite Cursor getColumnIndex() is case sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9029668/android-sqlite-cursor-getcolumnindex-is-case-sensitive)

```
public int getPercentage(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + PERCENTAGE + " FROM " + TABLE + " WHERE " + PERCENTAGE + " = " + 22 + ";", null);
    int i = 0;
    if (c.moveToFirst())
    {
        int colIdx = c.getColumnIndex(PERCENTAGE);
        if (colIdx != -1) // Column exists
            i = c.getInt(colIdx);  //Line 54
    }
    c.close();
    return i;
}
```

Comment: Updated my answer due to my negligence in noticing you had constants defined but weren't using them consistently.

Comment: Ugh, never even thought of case sensitivity, seeing that we're talking about SQL here.  I think you're right ;)

Comment: Me neither till I wondered why didn't he get an error when he tried to select a column that didn't exist earlier, thanks :D

Comment: Ahh I just looked over the code for 10 minutes and cannot see what I did wrong with case sensitivity and constants.  Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 2):

Building off of David's comment:

```
public int getPercentage(SQLiteDatabase db) {
     Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + PERCENTAGE + " FROM " + TABLE + " WHERE " + PERCENTAGE + " = " + 22 + ";", null);
     if(c.getCount() != 0){
            c.moveToFirst();
            int i = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(PERCENTAGE));  //Line 54
            return i;
     } else { return 0 }
}
```

Use the constant consistently, and make sure it's exactly like your sqllite DB.  Apparently getColumnIndex is case sensitive ;)

Comment: I wrote my own version of ````getPercentage()```` and ````getScore()```` but the exception is still present.  Also, in my updated methods in my opening post, do I have something wrong with my case sensitivity?  I am not sure where you and Salman are referring to.

Comment: What we meant by consistently using the constants, is that you defined a variable for the column name `private static final String PERCENTAGE = "percentage";` but you use a string to refer to the same column name when you call `c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("PERCENTAGE"));`.  The constant is there, use it :P  As for case sensitivity, `getColumnIndex("PERCENTAGE")` and `getColumnIndex("percentage")` aren't the same thing, even though sqlite is case insensitive.  try using your constant in that method call, assuming your column name is actually "percentage".