# ListView Memory Issue

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview, android-listview

I am using `listview`to store more then 50 item into the `listview` its working but after inserting the 20th item the erros showing in the log cat like this.

```
08-02 12:50:34.646: E/CursorWindow(5245): not growing since there are already 16 row(s), max size 1048576
08-02 12:50:34.646: E/Cursor(5245): Failed allocating 69485 bytes for text/blob at 24,8
08-02 12:50:34.695: D/Cursor(5245): finish_program_and_get_row_count row 25
08-02 12:50:35.365: E/CursorWindow(5245): need to grow: mSize = 1048576, size = 69485, freeSpace() = 9795, numRows = 16
08-02 12:50:35.365: E/CursorWindow(5245): not growing since there are already 16 row(s), max size 1048576
08-02 12:50:35.365: E/Cursor(5245): Failed allocating 69485 bytes for text/blob at 23,8
08-02 12:50:35.396: D/Cursor(5245): finish_program_and_get_row_count row 26
08-02 12:50:35.896: D/Cursor(5245): skip_rows row 7
08-02 12:50:35.905: E/CursorWindow(5245): need to grow: mSize = 1048576, size = 69485, 
freeSpace() = 9795, numRows = 16
08-02 12:50:35.905: E/CursorWindow(5245): not growing since there are already 16 row(s), max size 1048576
08-02 12:50:35.905: E/Cursor(5245): Failed allocating 69485 bytes for text/blob at 22,8
08-02 12:50:35.936: D/Cursor(5245): finish_program_and_get_row_count row 27
08-02 12:50:36.425: D/Cursor(5245): skip_rows row 6
08-02 12:50:36.436: E/CursorWindow(5245): need to grow: mSize = 1048576, size = 69485, 
freeSpace() = 9795, numRows = 16
```

and also the application is very slow to load. Help me.

Comment: What "items" are u trying to load into each row??

Comment: only strings like date year and some amount
example:  Date: 02-01-2012 Year:2011 Amount:2000$

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1408132/735675 see if this helps

Comment: ya i'm looking like this. thank you @Dya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is, We can't load more than 1 MB data from `sqlite` db in single `Cursor`. So have to avoid loading large datas into the list item. Alternate solution keep any unique ids for the lager data and call it a single data by `onClick List` item(Worked for me).

And the best solution is using `CursorJoiner` and follow this links

[how to load more than 1 MB data from sqlite db to android cursor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6938405/how-to-load-more-than-1-mb-data-from-sqlite-db-to-android-cursor)

[Android SQL Lite fail to grow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561085/android-sql-lite-fail-to-grow)